# Best practice - Declaring an event as part of a Java interface

Tags: java, events

I'm attempting to decouple some UI code using interfaces and events, and I would like to know  if there is way/best practice in Java for declaring an event as part of a Java interface - something like what C# provides:

```
// C# event declaration in interface
public interface IAction
{
    event EventHandler OnAction;
}
```

My goal is simply to mark an interface so that it is known it (implementors) fires events of a particular type. I'm hoping I can include more than documentation only to enforce that behaviour. I realize Java does not provide the "event" keyword or a direct way of doing this, so I'm hoping for some advice on a workaround or best practice on achieving this.

One way I can think of doing this is by creating a generic marker interface that represents the capability to fire events:

```
public interface FiresEvent<T extends Event> {
    public void fireEvent();
}
```

... and then to inherit that interface in my custom interface.

```
public interface MyInterface extends FiresEvent<ActionEvent> {

}
```

The problem with this approach is that "FiresEvent" can only be inherited once, even if the generic type changes, so the solution does not seem generic enough for the case where an object may be the source of multiple events.

I'd be curious to know how people would handle this, and if there is a better way than to just document the need to fire events.

**EDIT:**
Maybe the following will clear up my question:

I understand the Java handler list approach and self-handling by allowing callers to register handlers against an object. In my case I am relying on an event bus, so we can view "firing" events as putting them out there, for something else to redirect to handlers.

I'd like to define the interface responsibility as:

- The interface implementer fires an event of type T into the world/event bus/anything
- The interface implementer does not have to delegate to registered listeners itself

Answer (score 4):

Java handles events a bit differently than what you're used to, however the concept is the same. You create what's called an event listener, and it's called when the event happens. This can be a better construct as it allows for multiple listeners to be registered.

I suggest browsing this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Comment: I'm comfortable with Java events, my question is about the best practice in specifying that an interface should throw events.

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/beans/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.java.htm

Comment: Java doesn't fire events, it calls registered listeners. So, if you want to mimic the C# model, you'll need to call registered listeners.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of a method

```
 registerXListener(XListener listener)
```

in the interface indicates that a class will send out XEvents to those that care. That is, the 'marker' is just another method. The nearest analog of the C# idiom (I think) would be to lift that method into an interface, like

```
public interface XEventFirer 
{
    public void registerXListener(XListener listener)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a natural place to use annotations.  I have come across [EventBus](http://www.eventbus.org) which uses annotations to for publishing and subscribing to events.  This approach is naturally self-documenting and depending on how it's implemented could make your code more readable and maybe allow you to enforce the annotation.

Comment: Another library (That is more type-safe than EventBus for this sort of thing) is GUTS-events - http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home

Comment: @Kevin That's good info...I think I'll read up on Guice, never heard of it.  Sounds like that package will do most of what the OP wants, but doesn't look like it is really good for marking event firers, at least on the class level.  Help me out if I'm confused.

Comment: you are correct - it doesn't have facilities for marking firers... honestly, I'm not quite sure that I follow the point of doing that sort of thing - if you are using an event bus, the last thing you want to do is worry about where the events come from.  I've never really understood the need for all these extra non-functional annotations, but that's probably a lack of imagination on my part. Using annotations to mark a *consumer* makes sense, because it allows the DI framework to deliver messages and reduces a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: PS - GUICE itself is a DI framework created by Google.  GUTS is a framework built on top of GUICE to provide event bus and slick rich client functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I have (been trying to) read up on it from the link you posted the other day.  I don't get to do much programming, so I'm out of the loop on hot design patterns.  Wasn't familiar with DI at all...thanks for educating me.