# How to define an event in a java interface

Tags: java, events, interface

I want to use RMI in my application. So using the interface is compulsory. I want to force the developer to implement event. So I want to declare the events methods in my interface. How can I do this? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: That's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224991/best-practice-declaring-an-event-as-part-of-a-java-interface

Answer (score 0):

`public void handleXXXEvent(XXXEventType event);`

Where `XXX` can be replaced with EventType and `XXXEventType` is instance of the event

It is best you can make your implementation classes to register to a `Listener`

like `public void registerToXXXListener(XXXListner listener);`

Comment: Could you please give me an example of this?

Comment: i can't as im not aware of your context/code. take this idea and apply to your context.post the code if you'r stuck somewhere ..that's how SO works :)